# Resources в своей папке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне говорили что можно использовать папку ресурсов в своей папке, но я не понимаю как к ней обратиться, к примеру есть папка AllIcons а в ней папке ресурсов с иконками, как туда обратиться?

Comment: в своей папке это где? в папке пользователя системы? или в папке с собранной игрой? или в папке где лежит проект запущенный в юнити эдитор?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в редакторе, оно же от туда комплит

Comment: Редактор - это редактор, а не файловая система, какой путь у вашей папки относительно проекта?

Comment: @k0vpack тоесть в собранной игре этот функционал не пртребуется?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [документации к Resources.Load(path)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html):

> Returns the asset at path if it can be found otherwise returns null.
>   Only an object of type T will be returned. **The path is relative to any
>   folder named Resources inside the Assets folder of your project**. **More
>   than one Resources folder can be used**. For example, a project may have
>   Resources folders called Assets/Resources and Assets/Guns/Resources.
>   String names that include Assets and Resources are not needed. For
>   example the loading of a GameObject at
>   Assets/Guns/Resources/Shotgun.prefab does not use the folder names.
>   Also, if Assets/Resources/Guns/Missiles/PlasmaGun.prefab exists it
>   will be loaded using Prefabs/Missiles/PlasmaGun. **If you have multiple
>   Resources folders you cannot duplicate use of an asset name**.

В проекте может быть хоть 100 папок с названием `Resources`, есть только 2 главных ограничения:

1. Эти папки должны содержать в своем пути папку `Assets` проекта
2. Эти папки не могут иметь файлы с одинаковым путем относительно папки Resources

---

### Пример использования

Для загрузки нужного ассета из ресурсов нужно указывать относительный к папке Resources путь, например:

Пути префабов:

```
Assets/Guns/Resources/Shotgun.prefab
Assets/Resources/Guns/Missiles/PlasmaGun.prefab
```

Загрузка префабов Shotgun.prefab и PlasmaGun.prefab:

```
var shotgun   = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Shotgun");
var plasmaGun = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Guns/Missiles/PlasmaGun");
```

---

### Что делать с файлами с одинаковым именем

Казалось бы, у файлов ниже разные пути, так что конфликтов быть не должно:

```
Assets/Resources/Enemy.prefab
Assets/Wounded/Resources/Enemy.prefab
```

А вот и нет, `Resources.Load(path)` принимает относительный к папке `Resources` путь, в данном случае в обоих случаях будет такая ситуация: `Resources.Load("Enemy")`. Т.е. мы потеряем возможность загрузить второй префаб.

Решение довольно простое и наглядное - нужно правильно файлы в проекте хранить и поменять пути на такие:

```
Assets/Resources/Enemy.prefab
Assets/Resources/Wounded/Enemy.prefab
```

Тогда пути для `Resources.Load(path)` будут такими:

```
var enemy        = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Enemy");
var woundedEnemy = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Wounded/Enemy");
```