# Консультация по поводу Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Пишу игру для андроида. Пошаговая РПГ. У меня есть инвентарь с предметами, предметы основываются на классе Item. Не могу понять, как мне лучше сделать массив этих предметов с картинками и другими полями, чтобы можно было получать и добавлять в инвентарь эти предметы. Они не должны находиться на сцене

Comment: вам нужен canvas ui https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html

Comment: В том то и дело, он у меня есть, и работает, у меня другой вопрос. Как мне создать массив из этих объектов, который будет содержать название изображений и характеристики, чтобы в канвасе я могла прикреплять эти изображения

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/987641/%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-prefab-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-canvasa?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и проблема заключается в том, что инвентарь и предметы не должны находиться на сцене, то ваш класс `Item` должен выгляделть примерно как-то так:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Item
{
    public Item(Sprite sprite, int cost)
    {
        _sprite = sprite;
        _cost = cost;
    }

    [SerializeField]
    Sprite _sprite;

    int _cost;

    // другие поля
}
```

А ваш инвентарь примерно так:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory
{
    static Inventory _instance;

    public static Inventory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new Inventory();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

    // используйте для добавления предмета в ваш "инвентарь"
    public void AddItem(Item item) => _items.Add(item);

    // используйте для удаления предмета из вашего "инвентаря"
    public void RemoveItem(Item item) => _items.Remove(item);
}
```

Ну и пример добавления предмета в инвентарь здесь:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RewardItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Sprite _sprite;//картинка предмета, который добавится в инвентарь

    // другие данные, которые будут нужны для создания предмета (чтобы его добавить в инв.)
    [SerializeField]
    int _cost;

    void Start()
    {
        // таким образом, если данный скрипт висит где-то на сцене,
        // то на старте в Инвентарь добавится новый предмет,
        // с указанной картинкой и, например, ценой
        Item myNewItem = new Item(_sprite, _cost);
        Inventory.Instance.AddItem(myNewItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасииибо)) И ещё маленький вопрос, как мне при создании Item указывать на ресурс sprite? Путь до папки с ним и его название? Ни где не смогла найти это)

Comment: @Кристина вы можете перетащить спрайт прямо из проекта в соответствующее поле типа `Sprite` у какого-нибудь объекта. Если этот способ вам не подходит, используйте поиск по ресурсам: `var sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("МояКартинка");` (подробнее здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958190/resources-в-своей-папке)

Comment: Спасииибо))))))